# Pointer gives abnormal values after deferencing

Tags: c++, pointers, robotics

I am trying to replicate a big C++ library. It has the following structure of code

RobotRunner.h

```
class RobotRunner
{
public:
    VectorNavData* vectorNavData;
};
```

RobotRunner.cpp

```
void RobotRunner::run()
{
printf("Quaternion[0]: %f \n", vectorNavData->quat[0]); //Output: 243235653487854 - Abnormal values
}
```

SimulationBridge.h

```
class SimulationBridge
{
private:
    VectorNavData _vectorNavData; // Actual value of vectornavdata from the robot is stored here
    
    RobotRunner* _robotRunner = nullptr; //Pointer to the RobotRunner Object
}
```

SimulationBridge.cpp

```
void SimulationBridge::init()
{
_robotRunner = new RobotRunner();

printf("Quaternion[0]: %f \n", _vectorNavData.quat[0]); // Output: 0.43 - Normal and expected
_robotRunner->vectorNavData = &_vectorNavData;
}

void SimulationBridge::run()
{
_robotRunner->run();
}

//This function runs continuously and updates the _vectorNavData in a separate thread
void SimulationBridge::readIMU()
{
    while(true)
    { 
        //_lowState stores the values of different robot parameters at a given time

        _vectorNavData.accelerometer[0] = _lowState.imu.accelerometer[0];
        _vectorNavData.accelerometer[1] = _lowState.imu.accelerometer[1];
        _vectorNavData.accelerometer[2] = _lowState.imu.accelerometer[2];

        _vectorNavData.quat[0] = _lowState.imu.quaternion[1];
        _vectorNavData.quat[1] = _lowState.imu.quaternion[2];
        _vectorNavData.quat[2] = _lowState.imu.quaternion[3];
        _vectorNavData.quat[3] = _lowState.imu.quaternion[0];

        _vectorNavData.gyro[0] = _lowState.imu.gyroscope[0];
        _vectorNavData.gyro[1] = _lowState.imu.gyroscope[1];
        _vectorNavData.gyro[2] = _lowState.imu.gyroscope[2];
    }
}
```

VectorNavData is a struct which stores the details about the orientation of the robot. It has the following definition

```
struct VectorNavData {
  Vec3<float> accelerometer;
  Vec3<float> gyro;
  Quat<float> quat;
};
```

I have included only the necessary part of the code here for brevity.

**Code Explanation:**

SimulationBridge class communicates with the robot in the simulation. It takes in vectorNavData and stores it in the member variable _vectorNavData. SimulationBridge also contains the pointer to the RobotRunner class as one of it's member. I am allocating the address of _vectorNavData object to the pointer _robotRunner->vectorNavData (check SimulationBridge.cpp). Inside the RobotRunner class I deference this pointer and use the values in other parts of the code.

**Problem:**

If I print the vectorNavData inside the SimulationBridge.cpp the values seems to be normal. But after assigning the pointer of the same object to the robot runner, if I print the values there the values seems to be abnormally high. My question is, is this way of using pointers for dynamic allocation recommended? If not what is the best alternative way I can use?

Another important point to note is, I am compiling the code with CMake and "-O3" optimization flag is set to the CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS. If I remove this flag, the code sorta works fine for the above object pointer but I am still getting similar error for another object pointer in another part of the code.  I have not included that here because it's pretty complex to describe the code structure and the problem essentially is the same.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. What is `VectorNavData`? What is `vectorNavData->quat`? How are all the shown member variables initialized?

Comment: Please show a [mre]

Comment: Sorry! I have edited the post for better clarity. I hope this is clear now. @Someprogrammerdude

Comment: You mention threads, Do you have proper synchronization or protection against data-races? Also will the `SimulationBridge` object never go out of scope or otherwise be destructed while `_robotRunner->run()` is executing? Will the `vectorNavData` pointer always be valid? Have you tried to use memory-debuggers (like e.g. [Valgrind](https://www.valgrind.org/)) to make sure there's no pointer problems?

Comment: I doubt this is a data-race problem because the value of vectorNavData is not changed anywhere apart from the readIMU() func. The SimulationBridge does not run out of scope, there is an infinite loop down defined after it starts other threads. Yes, the vectorNavData should be always valid. I have not tried the memory-debugging yet, thanks for the suggestion I'll try it out.

Comment: *The SimulationBridge does not run out of scope* -- So why is the `vectorNavData` pointer invalid?  Sounds like it *is* going out of scope, or at least, the instance is invalid or has become invalidated.  One thing you should realize -- programmer's many times do not know the real truth about their code until they actually debug it.

Comment: My guess would be `SimulationBridge` gets copied somewhere, please provide a [mre]

Comment: Do you mean the SimulationBridge object getting copied somewhere in the code? @AlanBirtles

Comment: yes, if `SimulationBridge ` is copied `_vectorNavData` will have a different address and your pointer will be invalid

Comment: @HariP19 *I have included only the necessary part of the code here for brevity* -- You missed the most important part of the code -- the creation, usage, and destruction of your `SimulatorBridge` object.  If `SimulationBridge` has a destructor that `delete`'s the pointer, and temporary copies of `SimulatorBridge` are created, then that is probably one reason `vectorNavData` becomes invalidated.  C++ doesn't work this way, where you can cherry-pick portions of the code you believe is causing the error.  We need to see the whole picture, and especially for memory related issues.